# Creating custom shortcut in Visio 2010

Tags: visio

I would like to create a shortcut to horizontally and vertically align two shapes at once. Currently I have to select both items, click F8, choose the horizontal and vertical align, and click okay. Too slow. I can record a macro which basically just produces

```
    Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Align visHorzAlignCenter, visVertAlignMiddle, False
```

... which works great, but it only associates to the current document. Is there a way to make that shortcut work on any document I open or create?

Answer (score 0):

I just created a new template based on the Detailed Network Diagram template but with the macro inserted into it. Seemed to be the only solution.